# Processing multiple select controls within jquery mobile form

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to process multiple input selects in a form each one has a unique name and id.
here is my first try, this is broken when y = value.val(); executes

```
        var selects = $("#pmWorkOrderProcedureStepsForm").find('select');
        $.each(selects,
            function(index, value)
            {
                y = value.val();
            });
```

I can see in chrome debug that value has a reference to something that looks like 
HTMLSelectElement#select-choice-400139826
Where select-choice-400139826 is my first select input name. 
How do I get just the name and the selected value of the input from here.
New to jquery mobile!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code snippet:

```
var selects = $("#pmWorkOrderProcedureStepsForm").find("select");
$.each(selects,function(){
    name = $(this).attr('name');
    value = $(this).val();
});
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/5xg6F/

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Glad to be of help.Please mark the answer as accepted if you think the question has been answered.